# How to check if sortOrder is ordered using fluent validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling, fluentvalidation

I'm writing some rules for validation for my controller.

I wanted to throw errors in my controller if a user sorts by anything other than asc or desc.

Defintion:

Accepts string values of asc , desc.  If not provided, defaults to asc. If something else specified, throws an HTTP-400.

I originally had the following code:

```
RuleFor(x => x.SortOrder).NotNull().WithMessage("Please sort by desc or asc");
```

But this would fail to meet the requirements. Because if a user didn't want to use the sorting param then this validation would still get triggered as it would appear null in the response.

Comment: If it need to be default to `asc`, then you can specify your property as `public string SortOrder {get; set;} = "asc;"`so that it would not be null

Comment: so simple thank you!

Comment: @user1672994 would I need error handling for example if a user enters "asccc" instead of "asc" in the backend ?

Comment: Then you should. If SortOrder is meant only for three state then you can use bool? to define the tristate behaviour